# How do I prevent Auctex from inserting the initial `\item` in an item-like environment?

Tags: auctex

Is there a way to customize Auctex, and in particular `LaTeX-env-item` so that it does *not* automatically insert the first `\item`, but still have working `LaTeX-insert-item` so that `C-c C-j` works? Looking at the source code of `LaTeX-env-item`, it looks like a call to `LaTeX-insert-item` is baked in.

The situation when this would be useful is when I select text

```
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
```

and press `C-c C-e` (insert environment), then get

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \item foo
\item bar
\item baz
\end{itemize}
```

It shouldn't be too hard for the machine to figure out that the extra `\item` is bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an advice of `LaTeX-env-item-region` (defined with [`advice-add`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html)), you can locally change the behavior of `LaTeX-insert-item` with the help of [`cl-letf*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Modify-Macros.html#index-cl_002dletf).
This is demonstrated in the code snippet below.
There, `LaTeX-env-item` uses `my-LaTeX-insert-item` when the region is active.
`my-LaTeX-insert-item` only inserts `\item` if it is not already present behind point.

```el
(defun my-LaTeX-insert-item (old-insert-item &rest args)
  "Use `LaTeX-insert-item' only if there is no \\item or when called interactively.
This function can be used as :around advice for `LaTeX-insert-item'.
OLD-INSERT-ITEM is the original version of `LaTeX-insert-item'
and ARGS is the list of its original arguments (which is currently empty)."
  (if (looking-at "[[:space:]]*\\\\item\\_>")
      (progn
    (insert "\n")
    (indent-according-to-mode)
    (forward-sexp)
    (cond
     ((looking-at "[[:space:]]")
      (forward-char))
     ((eolp)
      (TeX-parse-arguments (cdr-safe (assoc "item" (TeX-symbol-list)))))
     (t
      (forward-sexp)
      (if (looking-at "[[:space:]]")
          (forward-char)
        (insert " ")))))
    (apply old-insert-item args)))

;; (advice-add 'LaTeX-insert-item :around #'maybe-LaTeX-insert-item)

(defun my-LaTeX-env-item-region (fun &rest args)
  "Do not insert first item if region is active.
This function can be used as :around advice for `LaTeX-env-item'
with ARGS as its original argument list."
  (if (use-region-p)
      (cl-letf* ((old-insert-item (symbol-function 'LaTeX-insert-item))
         ((symbol-function 'LaTeX-insert-item)
          (lambda (&rest args)
            (apply #'my-LaTeX-insert-item old-insert-item args))))
    (apply fun args))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'LaTeX-env-item :around #'my-LaTeX-env-item-region)
```

Comment: TIL about `advice-add`.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I added links to the documentation of `advice-add` and `cl-letf`. While `advice-add` is for globally advising functions `cl-letf` can be used for locally advising functions (i.e., `let`-bound).